# How to do one-select linq-to-sql MAX query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, max

This code

```
int maxTrackId = dataContext.TicketTracks.Max(T => T.TrackId);
```

Generates the following `SQL` code:

```sql
SELECT MAX([t0].[TrackId]) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[TicketTracks] AS [t0]
```

But if the table is empty, I got an exception saing that nullable value cannot be assigned to non-nullable variable.

Then I write this code, explicitly telling the SQL provider that i need either maximum or null:

```
int? maxTrackId = dataContext.TicketTracks.Max(T => (int?)T.TrackId);
```

And it works fine on that non-nullable SQL column, giving me back either `null` or the number. But the `SQL` code generated is kind of strange:

```sql
SELECT MAX([t1].[value]) AS [value]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[TrackId] AS [value]
    FROM [dbo].[TicketTracks] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t1]
```

So it seems weird, especially with two `SELECT`s. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: Why do you think two selects does no perfomance difference?

Comment: I answered this in an answer more thoroughly.

Comment: @usr Could you link us to the answer and show us the numbers? That would be most helpful.

Comment: @JeffBridgman the answer is right below. Just look at the execution plan to see for yourself. Is there a reason you expect a difference? How could such a difference possibly manifest itself in an execution plan? I honestly cannot think of a way. Maybe an empty compute-scalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL might be convoluted but there is no performance difference. The SQL Server query optimizer reliably optimizes both statements to the same plan.

Really, removing a redundant nested select is a trivial case. I have never seen this cause a plan difference.

So it is an aesthetic problem, not a practical one. ORMs generate convoluted code and I learned to live with it.